# Change from horizontal to vertical positions of an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

For example I have an **array of objects**:

```
[
    {
      "position_x": 716,
      "position_y": 217,
    },
    {
      "position_x": 716,
      "position_y": 162,
    }
]
```

This json that I use to place elements in a **html5 canvas** and I get it through a service.

The problem that I have that this service returns me the **horizontal** positions and I wanted to know with what formula we can rotate the positions **x and y** so that it changes the direction to **vertical**.

Comment: Can you create a complete example?

Comment: 1. Use position_x for y and position_y for x. 2. Transform rotate the context or the canvas element

Comment: thankssss so much!